# Calculation of rolling distance between two columns in a sorted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question to which I have already received an answer in a similar context. However, I do not succeed in transferring the solution, and I am grateful for any hint where I make the mistake.

I want to calculate the distance (headway) between an ArucoID *i* and the preceding ArucoID *i+1* in the direction of movement for each frameID. Basically, this is the calculation of the distance between values from two columns of a sorted and grouped data frame. Then I want to apply the rolling mean to this distance (rolling_headway) as well.

I expect, that the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73834673/calculation-of-rolling-speed-in-a-pandasdataframe) proposed by @jlandercy should work analogously:

**The data is:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'ArucoID' : [910, 910, 910, 910, 910, 898, 898, 898, 898, 898, 912, 912, 912, 912, 912],
    'Subtrial' : ['01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01', '01'],
    'frameID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'xPos' : [10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 12.0, 13, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 9.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 4.0 ],
    'yPos' : [-0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.05, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05],
}

data2 = {
    'ArucoID' : [910, 910, 910, 910, 910, 898, 898, 898, 898, 898, 912, 912, 912, 912, 912],
    'Subtrial' : ['02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02', '02'],
    'frameID' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'xPos' : [9.4, 9.5, 9.0, 9.0, 10, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 3.5, 5.0 ],
    'yPos' : [-0.2, -0.1, -0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.05, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.05],
}

df_raw = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(data1),
    pd.DataFrame(data2) 
])
```

**My attempt:**

1. Sorting the df by frameID. Here it is important that the ArucoID remain unsorted, because the order is not necessarily ascending. In other words, I want to keep the order of the ArucoIDs.

```
df = df_raw.sort_values(["Subtrial", "frameID"])
```

2. Determination of the shifted x-position (direction of movement is in x-direction):

```
shifted = df.groupby(["Subtrial"]).shift(-1)
#print(shifted)
shifted = shifted.drop("frameID", axis=1).rename(columns=lambda x: x + "_")
data = pd.concat([df, shifted], axis=1)
```

3. Calculation of headway in point (frame):

```
def dX(x):
    return np.sqrt(np.power(x["xPos"] - x["xPos_"], 2))
        
data['point_headway'] = data.apply(dX, axis=1)
```

4. Sort the dfs by ArucoID and Subtrial (because I would like to have the rolling mean for the specific ArucoID), then apply the rolling mean (assuming a window size of 3 here).

```
data["rolling_headway"] = data.sort_values(["Subtrial", "ArucoID",'frameID']).groupby(["Subtrial", "ArucoID"]).rolling(3, min_periods=2).mean()["point_headway"].values
#print(data)
```

It results in:

```
    frameID  xPos  yPos  ...  ArucoID_ point_headway  rolling_headway
5         1   4.0  0.20  ...     912.0           2.5         2.750000
6         2   5.0  0.20  ...     912.0           3.0         4.166667
7         3   6.0 -0.10  ...     912.0           3.5         5.500000
8         4   7.0  0.00  ...     912.0           4.0              NaN
9         5   9.0  0.05  ...     912.0           5.0         9.500000
```

What I expected (see last column)

```
    frameID  xPos  yPos  ...  ArucoID_ point_headway    expected
5         1   4.0  0.20  ...     912.0           2.5         NaN
6         2   5.0  0.20  ...     912.0           3.0         NaN
7         3   6.0 -0.10  ...     912.0           3.5         3.000000 (2.5+3.0+3.5)/3
8         4   7.0  0.00  ...     912.0           4.0         3.500000 (3.0+3.5+4.0)/3
9         5   9.0  0.05  ...     912.0           5.0         4.166667 (3.5+4.0+5.0)/3
```

Where do I have the mistake in thinking? I think I'm sorting wrong, aren't I?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Why do you square and then take the square root of the same value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = df_raw.sort_values(["Subtrial", "frameID"])

# I wasn't sure what your were doing here... 
# absolute value was the only thing that made sense.
# I also didn't bother to make all those new columns.
df['point_headway'] = df.xPos.sub(df.groupby('Subtrial').xPos.shift(-1)).abs()

# I ignore_index here, so that the order is what you seem to expect.
df = df.sort_values(["Subtrial", "ArucoID",'frameID'], ignore_index=True)

# Your issue was here. You explicitly called `.values`,
# Probably to avoid an error. But you ended up losing your indexing,
# which was all over the place due to your sortings.
df["rolling_headway"] = (df.groupby(['Subtrial', 'ArucoID'])['point_headway']
                           .apply(lambda x: x.rolling(3).mean()))
# I used apply, just because it drops all the groupby key data and gives us our original index.

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    ArucoID Subtrial  frameID  xPos  yPos  point_headway  rolling_headway
0       898       01        1   4.0  0.20            2.5              NaN
1       898       01        2   5.0  0.20            3.0              NaN
2       898       01        3   6.0 -0.10            3.5         3.000000
3       898       01        4   7.0  0.00            4.0         3.500000
4       898       01        5   9.0  0.05            5.0         4.166667
5       910       01        1  10.0 -0.20            6.0              NaN
6       910       01        2  10.5 -0.10            5.5              NaN
7       910       01        3  11.0 -0.10            5.0         5.500000
8       910       01        4  12.0  0.00            5.0         5.166667
9       910       01        5  13.0  0.00            4.0         4.666667
10      912       01        1   1.5 -0.20            9.0              NaN
11      912       01        2   2.0 -0.10            9.0              NaN
12      912       01        3   2.5  0.00            9.5         9.166667
13      912       01        4   3.0  0.10           10.0         9.500000
14      912       01        5   4.0  0.05            NaN              NaN
15      898       02        1   3.0  0.20            0.5              NaN
16      898       02        2   4.0  0.20            1.0              NaN
17      898       02        3   5.0 -0.10            1.5         1.000000
18      898       02        4   6.0  0.00            2.5         1.666667
19      898       02        5   7.0  0.05            2.0         2.000000
20      910       02        1   9.4 -0.20            6.4              NaN
21      910       02        2   9.5 -0.10            5.5              NaN
22      910       02        3   9.0 -0.10            4.0         5.300000
23      910       02        4   9.0  0.00            3.0         4.166667
24      910       02        5  10.0  0.00            3.0         3.333333
25      912       02        1   2.5 -0.20            7.0              NaN
26      912       02        2   3.0 -0.10            6.0              NaN
27      912       02        3   3.5  0.00            5.5         6.166667
28      912       02        4   3.5  0.10            6.5         6.000000
29      912       02        5   5.0  0.05            NaN              NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the incredibly fast answer and the detailed tips. 

The approach with df.xPos.sub() is much shorter, more elegant and easier to read than the way to insert the shift via a separate dataframe. Thanks!

And indeed, you guess exactly right: I choose '.values', because I got errors. But of course, with that, I kill the index. Thanks for your help and explanations!